# Replacing values in large number of columns with another column value based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data:

```
id   |  d1   |  d2  |  d3  | .... |  d64   | FINAL_GRADE
1    |  0    |  15  |  0   | .... |  23    | 95
2    |  8    |  0   |  12  | .... |  0     | 75
```

And I want to replace all non-zero values in each row with the corresponding value in the `FINAL_GRADE` column, and obtain this table:

```
id   |  d1   |  d2  |  d3  | .... |  d64   | FINAL_GRADE
1    |  0    |  95  |  0   | .... |  95    | 95
2    |  75   |  0   |  75  | .... |  0     | 75
```

Here is my code:

```
df[df.ix[:, 1:63] != 0] = df['FINAL_GRADE']
```

But, I am receiving this error: `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

I wonder if my code has any issues? Or my approach is totally wrong. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [`DF.mask()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method on the created boolean mask.

Using `.ix` for setting values fails here presumably because you're operating on the subset of columns having mixed `dtypes` (`float` - due to the generation of the bool mask and subsetting operation & `int` - values in *FINAL_GRADE* to be looked up at).

This would be the main cause of the `TypeError` getting generated.

***Steps:***

1) Subset the dataframe by selecting the columns starting with the char *d* using `str.startswith`.

2) Using `DF.mask` for the conditions wherein the values in this subset are non-zero, we replace them with the contents present in *FINAL_GRADE* row-wise by specifying `axis=0`.

3) Finally, concatenate the *id*, *FINAL_GRADE* and the masked `DF` column-wise using `pd.concat`(`axis=1`)

---

```
sub_df = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('d')]]
mask_df = sub_df.mask(sub_df != 0, df['FINAL_GRADE'], axis=0)
pd.concat([df['id'], mask_df, df['FINAL_GRADE']], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! Could you please add some explanations ?

Comment: I've provided adequate explanation regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

The following might be slightly more crude than strictly necessary, but I think it is a clean and generalized fit for your problem:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    row[0:-1][row != 0] = row.FINAL_GRADE
```

Note that I'm doing a couple of things here, so some notes:

1. `row[0:-1]` will address all row items except the last one, so .ix is not necessary when using integer indexes for this case, and you are not locked into the case where you have *exactly* 64 columns.
2. I am looping over all rows, which is generally not considered the most efficient way of doing things, but I find it readable and sufficiently ok for cases such as yours that are not high-performance calculations repeated hundreds of times.
3. `_` is convention for ignoring a variable, which in this case is the row index that `iterrows()` automatically gives me.
4. Try to use `.loc` more than `.ix` because it leverages the semantic benefit that labelling your data gives you.

I'll try to think of a solution without a for loop that is considered pythonic and not too contrived or unreadable.

**EDIT:**
Found a one-liner that is in my opinion both readable and simple/general enough to be applied to other/similar problems:

```
df.ix[:, 0:-1] = df.ix[:, 0:-1].where(df == 0, df.FINAL_GRADE, axis=0)
```